# How do I conditionally set environment variables in my travis.yml?

Tags: travis-ci

I would like to conditional set some environment variables in my `travis.yml` but can't find documentation that covers what I'm attempting, and now wonder whether it's even possible.

What I'd like to do is something like

```
env:
- $RESOLVER="lts-6.35"
- $RESOLVER="lts-7.24"
- $RESOLVER="lts-9.21"
- $RESOLVER="lts-10.3"
- $RESOLVER="lts-11.22"
- $RESOLVER="lts-12.11"
if: branch = master
- $RESOLVER="nightly"     # Exclude from hackage branch

if: $RESOLVER = "nightly"
- $STACKYAML="post86.yaml"
if: $RESOLVER != "nightly"
- $STACKYAML="pre86.yaml"
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to create different jobs, each with its own set of env vars.  You'd do something like:

```
jobs:
  include:
    - if: branch = master
      env: 
      - RESOLVER="nightly"
      - STACKYAML="post86.yml"
    - if: NOT (branch = master)
      env:
      - RESOLVER="lts-12.11"
      - STACKYAML="pre86.yml"
```

One thing to be aware of, is if multiple jobs are simultaneously true, travis will launch multiple simultaneous jobs, so if you don't want a commit to kick off multiple jobs, be careful to make sure that the conditions are mutually exclusive, as they are in this case.